# Expand Donkey Kong Country Wii tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The following tags related to Donkey Kong Country should be renamed, thanks to the 35 character tag limit:

- [dk-country-returns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dk-country-returns) → [donkey-kong-country-returns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong-country-returns)
- [dkc-tropical-freeze](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dkc-tropical-freeze) → [donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze)

Given that [donkey-kong-country-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong-country-3) does not have any synonyms, I don't think that any are necessary here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed.  I've created [donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong-country-tropical-freeze) and mapped [dkc-tropical-freeze](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dkc-tropical-freeze) to it.

I've created [donkey-kong-country-returns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donkey-kong-country-returns) and **deleted** [dk-country-returns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dk-country-returns). I deleted the original tag since DK Country is never how anyone ever refers to that series. It's either Donkey Kong Country or DKC.